# php code is not executing?

Tags: php, oop

```
<?php
class abhi
{
    var $contents="default_abhi";

    function abhi($contents)
    {
        $this->$contents = $contents;
    }

    function get_whats_there()
    {
        return $this->$contents;
    }

}

$abhilash = new abhi("abhibutu");
echo $abhilash->get_whats_there();

?>
```

i've initialized variable contents a default and also constructor, why is the value not printing, anything i should correct here?

see the error,

```
abhilash@abhilash:~$ php5 pgm2.php 

Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in /home/abhilash/pgm2.php on line 13
abhilash@abhilash:~$
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are returning the variable incorrectly inside the function. It should be:

```
return $this->contents
```

Comment: What Extrakun means is that you don't include the $ when setting or accessing an object's variables.

Comment: There's actually another problem, too... the echo statement requires a dollar sign before the abhilash variable name.

Comment: As a further explanation why it is valid syntax, you can store a function name into a variable and invoke it by putting the brackets behind it, which is why PHP complains it as an 'empty property'

Answer (score 5):

Since the question is tagged as "php**5**" here's an example of your class with [php5 class notation](http://docs.php.net/oop5) (i.e. public/protected/private instead of var, public/protected/private function, __construct() instead of classname(), ...)

```
class abhi {
  protected $contents="default_abhi";

  public function __construct($contents) {
    $this->contents = $contents;
  }

  public function get_whats_there() {
    return $this->contents;
  }
}

$abhilash = new abhi("abhibutu");
echo $abhilash->get_whats_there();
```

Comment: Is there any reason to re-assign contents in the constructor? I know the original poster did, but is there a value to it?

Comment: @Tom: You can set contents at runtime via `$a = new abhi('new content')`

Comment: @Tom: Not really in this case. But fi another class extends abhi and its constructor doesn't call abhi::__construct() $contents will at least be set to "default_abhi" which might be sufficient in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

If i recall correctly it would be

```
$this->contents = $contents;
```

not

```
$this->$contents = $contents;
```

Answer (score 3):

Should be accessing and writing to $this->contents not $this->$contents

Answer (score 1):

Also, are you not missing a dollar-sign in "echo abhilash->get_whats_there();"? ($abhilash->..)

Answer (score 0):

use $this->contents  
i too at first had the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with $:
1. when using $this-> you do not put $ between "->" and the variable name the "$" sign, so your $this->$contents should be $this->contents.
2. in your echo youforgot the $ when calling that function from the instantiated class.

So your correct code is:

```
<?php
class abhi
{
    var $contents="default_abhi";

    function abhi($contents)
    {
        $this->contents = $contents;
    }

    function get_whats_there()
    {
        return $this->contents;
    }

}

$abhilash = new abhi("abhibutu");
echo $abhilash->get_whats_there();

?>
```